# Spring Data Redis : Is there a way to determine which redis node is spring querying against?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

Im pretty new to Redis and im trying to implement redis using spring data redis making redis as a storage database.
We have a master and two slaves and we included readOnly configuration from slave(SLAVE_PREFFERED).

Now, I would like to know if there is a way to know which redis node is being used to query the data when my application is using the database.

Thanks.

Comment: may be by redis logs

Comment: Any particular reason why this is needed in the application layer? Systems such as Redis is typically run in a cluster to ensure high-availability so that even if one node goes down, some other node from the cluster serves the client. Such a system needs the client to be abstracted out from the underlying node so that the nodes can be added/removed/replaced without the application being affected.